# Q2. Unable to install/activate jupyter_http_over_ws for Jupyter on Google Colab

Tags: runtime, jupyter, google-colaboratory, local

For Local runtimes, Colaboratory lets you connect to a local runtime using Jupyter. This allows you to execute code on your local hardware and have access to your local file system. I am trying to make jupyter_http_over_ws work.

Running these scripts accordingly but I am getting stuck and it is bouncing with errors-Screenshot 1.

I even tried running the last scripts to Start the server and authenticate but getting stuck but it too is getting frozen at a point- Screenshot 2.

```
pip install jupyter_http_over_ws
jupyter serverextension enable --py jupyter_http_over_ws


jupyter notebook \
  --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' \
  --port=8888 \
  --NotebookApp.port_retries=0
```

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RwSMP.png)

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8bIo0.png)

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have installed jupyter notebook and `jupyter_http_over_ws` properly, then execute this in command prompt:

```
jupyter notebook --NotebookApp.allow_origin='https://colab.research.google.com' --port=8888
```

Comment: By “write this down” I assume you mean “execute this”?

Comment: I obviously installed Jupyter notebook. How else would I open this particular terminal to execute the code?

Comment: @AnirbanB if jupyter notebook and jupyter_http_over_ws are installed successfully then I suggest you to remove "\" in the jupyter notebook code you posted and write all arguments in one line. If it still doesn't work then you'd better reinstall jupyter notebook and jupyter_http_over_ws

Comment: @JeremyCaney yes. Noted!